# listening event after id changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify an Id of button 'B' when  button 'A' is clicked, and listen to the click event of of 'B' using Jquery but my code doesn't work,
this is an example of my code:

```
$(function() {

    $(".nuttonA").click(
        function() {

            $("#buttonB").attr("id","notButtonB");
        });

    $("#notButtonB").click(function(){
        console.log(" notButtonB is clicked "); //show nothing
    });
});
```

Comment: why do you want to change the id ? maybe add a class or a data-attribute that you listen on

Comment: I want to understand Javascript behavior in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need event delegation. try this:

```
$(function() {

    $(".buttonA").click(
        function() {

            $("#buttonB").attr("id","notButtonB");
        });

    $( "body" ).on( "click", "#notButtonB",function(){
        console.log(" notButtonB is clicked "); //show nothing
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using delegated-events approach when manipulation properties.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', ".nuttonA", function(){
    $("#buttonB").attr("id","notButtonB");
});
$(document).on('click', "#notButtonB", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.